Salesforce Order Summary creation API
So please take a look at this url
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.order_management_developer_guide.meta/order_management_developer_guide/connect_resources_sfom_order_summaries.htm
So when I call this API through mule or even in postman I get a 400 bad request and I am unable to understand why this is happening. I am going to post my CURL as well
curl --location 'https://facetechnologies--partialdtc.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v58.0/commerce/order-management/order-summaries' 
--header 'Authorization: Bearer 00DOsgfe90000sdssd01wkbghfffffdtddsdN!chocolateMilkshake_becon.0jF.Q4BtssomethingExtrakilo90NUmber233esayCeasyzytf0sdgdw7FUNwTqe1rnTgdlysdsdWdzeL4CkHVsdsdsJOjBRpnVcfRuZjdHkeFAWsddsdds9B' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--header 'Cookie: BrowserId=02SthRjmEe-vCPfD5vgQDg; CookieConsentPolicy=0:1; LSKey-c$CookieConsentPolicy=0:1' 
--data '{
"orderId": "801O900000O8Y5CIAV"
}'

The question is really about how to use that Salesforce API? There are no programming details in the question. Questions asking for customer support with third-party services are off-topic for Stackoverflow, which is a programming Q&A site. You should contact Salesforce Support instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for details.

Fair enough. I thought, I might be making a mistake. Hence I posted. I'll try to contact the SF support instead.
